# Reading strings array list from text file instead of strings.xml

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

How to add lines or paragraphs into viewpager from text file in Android.
Example

Text file

absd efgh ijkl mno pqr Stu vwx yz

absd efgh ijkl mno pqr Stu vwx yz

absd efgh ijkl mno pqr Stu vwx yz

I want to read these 3 lines in viewpager for swiping

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to read from a file name `StringsFile.txt` in folder `\app\src\main\assets`, store them in `ArrrayList` to use in `ViewPager`. This will store blank lines as well, but you can easily filter them out.

```
    InputStream in;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line;
    ArrayList<String> listOfStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    try {

        in = this.getAssets().open("StringsFile.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            listOfStrings.add(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (String oneLine : listOfStrings)
        Log.d("TAG", "What I read is: " + oneLine);
```